# Elasticsearch date range issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm learning Elasticsearch and have an issue with date range queries. My queries compare only days, not the whole dates. Here's a short example:

```
DELETE test

PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "date" : {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dd MM YYYY"
        }
      }

  }
}

POST /_bulk
{"index" : {"_index": "test"}}
{"date": "01 01 2001"}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "lt": "01 01 2016",
        "gt": "01 01 2000"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "lte": "01 01 2000",
        "gte": "01 01 2016"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From my understanding the first search query should return the document - the date 2001 is < 2016 and > 2000. The second query should return nothing because 2001 is not <= 2000 and >=2016. But it works completely opposite.

Could you please point me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is failing is because ES is not formatting your date appropriately. The date formatting behavior changed between 6.x and 7.0 and [joda based date formatters are replaced with java ones](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_joda_based_date_formatters_are_replaced_with_java_ones). If you change your format to `"format": "dd MM yyyy"` (Note the lower case `yyyy`), you will find your search works.

The reason for the format not working, is that `YYYY` signifies [date week year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). You almost always want to have a lower case `yyyy` format to signify your year in your date format.

Comment: Thank you, I was expecting something like that. Seems it's not wise to do exercises based on older version of Elasticsearch.